# Pegar objeto filho - firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, realtime-database

Tenho um banco firebase nessa estrutura:

```
{
  "-L4Wqs3YbAlUgTWElF4Q" : {
    "receita" : {
      "-L6m_C46-Mj1py6RtF8H" : {
        "imagem" : "default",
        "ingrediente" : [ "ovo", "leite" ],
        "nome" : "um nome",
        "preparo" : "um preparo",
        "tipo" : true
      },
      "-L6m_Finc29fAlqU0nqe" : {
        "imagem" : "default",
        "ingrediente" : [ "amendoim" ],
        "nome" : "teste",
        "preparo" : "teste",
        "tipo" : false
      }
    },
    "senha" : "123456789",
    "usuario" : "guilherme"
  },
  "-L4WrImJ05VhzBgKHX6S" : {
    "senha" : "123456789",
    "usuario" : "patricia"
  }
}
```

Tenho usuários e os usuários possuem receitas, como pegar as receitas de todos os usuário que o tipo for `true`?

Minha função de leitura:

```
function ler() {
    firebase.database().ref(referencia_database).orderByChild('nome').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var chave = childSnapshot.key
            var obj = childSnapshot.val()
            var url

            if(obj.imagem == './image/default.png')
                url = './image/default.png'
            else
                url = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/receitas-alpha.appspot.com/o/' + chave + '%2F' + obj.imagem + '?alt=media&token=c634d1db-dc4c-4cb9-8630-fbedff537237'

            mostrar(chave, obj.nome, url)
        })
    })
}
```

`referencia_database` é `chave_usuario_logado + '/receita/'`

Quero fazer essa consulta mantendo a ordenação pelo nome

Comment: Qual a estrutura de `snapshot` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, vamos por partes.

#### Primeiro: Encontrar as receitas de todos os usuários

Pela forma como você estruturou os seus dados, não é possível encontrar todas as receitas. Eu sugiro que você altere a estrutura de dados para ter um nó "receitas" e um nó "usuarios":

```
{
  "usuarios":{
    "-L4WrImJ05VhzBgKHX6S" : {
      "senha" : "123456789",
      "usuario" : "patricia"
    },
    "-L4Wqs3YbAlUgTWElF4Q" : {
      "senha" : "123456789",
      "usuario" : "guilherme"
    }
  },
  "receitas":{
      "-L6m_C46-Mj1py6RtF8H" : {
        "imagem" : "default",
        "ingrediente" : [ "ovo", "leite" ],
        "nome" : "um nome",
        "preparo" : "um preparo",
        "tipo" : true,
        "usuario":"-L4WrImJ05VhzBgKHX6S"
      },
      "-L6m_Finc29fAlqU0nqe" : {
        "imagem" : "default",
        "ingrediente" : [ "amendoim" ],
        "nome" : "teste",
        "preparo" : "teste",
        "tipo" : false,
        "usuario":"-L4WrImJ05VhzBgKHX6S"
      }
  }
}
```

Note que eu adicionei também um atributo "usuario" caso você precise saber à quem pertence cada receita.

Assim, para achar todas as receitas com tipo=true você faria:

```
firebase.database().ref('receitas').orderByChild('tipo').equalTo(true)
```

#### Segundo: mantendo a ordenação por nome

Você mencionou que quer manter a ordenação por nome. O Firebase não permite fazer a ordenação por 2 atributos (tipo e nome seu caso). Você terá de agrupar estes 2 num 3º atributo (chamarei tipo_nome) e usar ele para ordenar. Este atributo irá conter o tipo concatenado com o nome da receita.

Então o nó receitas ficaria assim:

```
  "receitas":{
      "-L6m_C46-Mj1py6RtF8H" : {
        "imagem" : "default",
        "ingrediente" : [ "ovo", "leite" ],
        "nome" : "um nome",
        "preparo" : "um preparo",
        "tipo" : true,
        "tipo_nome":"true_um nome",
        "usuario":"-L4WrImJ05VhzBgKHX6S"
      },
      "-L6m_Finc29fAlqU0nqe" : {
        "imagem" : "default",
        "ingrediente" : [ "amendoim" ],
        "nome" : "teste",
        "preparo" : "teste",
        "tipo" : false,
        "tipo_nome":"false_teste",
        "usuario":"-L4WrImJ05VhzBgKHX6S"
      }
  }
```

E o código ficaria:

```
firebase.database().ref('receitas').orderByChild('tipo_nome').startAt('true_').endAt('true_\uf8ff');
```

No `endAt` utilizei o `\uf8ff` porque é o caracter mais elevado no intervalo unicode.

Comment: Teria como fazer o que pedi sem mudar a estrutura dos dados? Apenas por curiosidade, vou mudar a minha estrutura

Comment: Eu acho que não tem não. Esta é a melhor maneira que eu vejo.