# Mudar estrutura banco firebase

Tags: firebase, estrutura-de-dados, realtime-database

Fiz uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280803/pegar-objeto-filho-firebase) aqui no SOpt sobre como fazer uma busca no firebase realtime database, e @RosárioPereiraFernandes sugeriu mudar a estrutura do banco

Estrutura antiga:

```
{
  "-L4Wqs3YbAlUgTWElF4Q" : {
    "receita" : {
      "-L6m_C46-Mj1py6RtF8H" : {
        "imagem" : "default",
        "ingrediente" : [ "ovo", "leite" ],
        "nome" : "um nome",
        "preparo" : "um preparo",
        "tipo" : true
      },
      "-L6m_Finc29fAlqU0nqe" : {
        "imagem" : "default",
        "ingrediente" : [ "amendoim" ],
        "nome" : "teste",
        "preparo" : "teste",
        "tipo" : false
      }
    },
    "senha" : "123456789",
    "usuario" : "guilherme"
  },
  "-L4WrImJ05VhzBgKHX6S" : {
    "senha" : "123456789",
    "usuario" : "patricia"
  }
}
```

Estrutura nova:

```
{
  "usuarios":{
    "-L4WrImJ05VhzBgKHX6S" : {
      "senha" : "123456789",
      "usuario" : "patricia"
    },
    "-L4Wqs3YbAlUgTWElF4Q" : {
      "senha" : "123456789",
      "usuario" : "guilherme"
    }
  },
  "receitas":{
      "-L6m_C46-Mj1py6RtF8H" : {
        "imagem" : "default",
        "ingrediente" : [ "ovo", "leite" ],
        "nome" : "um nome",
        "preparo" : "um preparo",
        "tipo" : true,
        "usuario":"-L4WrImJ05VhzBgKHX6S"
      },
      "-L6m_Finc29fAlqU0nqe" : {
        "imagem" : "default",
        "ingrediente" : [ "amendoim" ],
        "nome" : "teste",
        "preparo" : "teste",
        "tipo" : false,
        "usuario":"-L4WrImJ05VhzBgKHX6S"
      }
  }
}
```

Não é o caso, mas e se eu quisesse alterar em banco que já está em produção e possui milhões de usuários? Algo com JavaScript ou direto no console do Firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui criar um código com JavaScript para alterar a estrutura do banco, porém devido ao fato do firebase ser assíncrono precisei de várias gambi...

Pra começar criei uma base com alguns usuarios e receitas:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var chave = firebase.database().ref('/usuarios').push().key

    firebase.database().ref('/usuarios/'+chave).set({
        usuario: 'teste',
        senha: 'teste'
    })

    for(var y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
        var _chave = firebase.database().ref('usuarios/'+chave+'/receitas').push().key

        firebase.database().ref('usuarios/'+chave+'/receitas/'+_chave).set({
            nome: 'teste',
            ingrediente: ['teste', 'teste', 'teste'],
            preparo: 'teste',
            imagem: 'teste.png'
        })
    }
}
```

E o código para alterar a estrutura + gambi:

```
//array com para adicionar as chaves do usuário
var json = []
firebase.database().ref('usuarios').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var chave = childSnapshot.key

        json.push({chave: chave})
    })
})

//Função para ler uma receita e adiciona-la em outro array
function ler(i) {
    firebase.database().ref('usuarios/'+json[i].chave+'/receitas').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
            var chave = child.key
            var obj = child.val()

            _json.push({chave: json[i].chave, _chave: chave, obj: obj})
        })
    })
}

//O array com as receitas
var _json = []
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    ler(i)
}

//Loop para cadastrar as receitas (no novo lugar) com os valores do segundo array
for(var i = 0; i < _json.length; i++) {
    firebase.database().ref('/receitas/'+_json[i]._chave).set({
        nome: _json[i].obj.nome,
        preparo: _json[i].obj.preparo,
        ingrediente: _json[i].obj.ingrediente,
        usuario: _json[i].chave
    })
}

//Loop para excluir as receitas, já cadastradas novo lugar
for(var i = 0; i < _json.length; i++) {
    firebase.database().ref('/usuarios/'+_json[i].chave+'/receitas/'+_json[i]._chave).remove()
}
```

Porque uma função `ler()`? Como o Firebase é assíncrono a variável `i` não chega em um loop dentro do `forEach()` do firebase com o valor correto, quando ela chegar já vai estar com algum outro valor maior, pois o loop do JavaScript é executado várias vezes até que seja feito 1 loop do `forEach()`

Provavelmente tem como melhorar esse código para deixar o mesmo mais performático, mas funciona